# centering my navigation bar

Tags: navigation, centering, nav

I'm trying to center my horizontal navigation bar. It's a little off to the right I'm not sure how. I have tried many of the other similar solutions posted here but nothing seems to center my navigation properly. Please can anyone help? Below is my HTML followed by my CSS.
Thanks!

**My HTML:**

```
<div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="box"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="box"><a href="earing/earing.html">Earrings</a></li>
                <li class="box"><a href="necklace/necklace.html">Pendants</a></li>
                <li class="box"><a href="rings/rings.html">Rings</a></li>
                <li class="box"><a href="sets/sets.html">Sets</a></li>
                <li class="box"><a href="orders/order.html">Order</a></li>
                <li class="box"><a href="contact/contactform.php">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
   </div>
```

**My CSS:**

```
#nav {
width: auto;
min-width: 1000px;
max-width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

#nav li, #nav a {
display: inline;
background-color: #E5D9CF;
padding: 10px;
margin: 10px;
border-radius: 25px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #403D3A;
font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
min-width: 80%;
} 

#nav a:hover {
color: #16B5D9;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your CSS

```
#nav ul {
    padding: 0px;
}
```